# How to save checkmark status of tableview cell xcode 12 swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple app similar to to-do list. I used `TableViewController` and I was able to set the checkmark accessory type for each row, also found a way to save the rows data so that when the app relaunches the list of items are shown again.

I want to save the checkmark state for all the rows. I tried other queries in Stack Overflow most of them are outdated.

here's my code to the app

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var shoppingList = [ShoppingList]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "Shopping List"
       
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))
        
        let clearList = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear List", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(clearList))
        
        toolbarItems = [clearList]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
        
        load()
        
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView() // clears the unused seperator lines
   
    }
    
    @objc func clearList() {
        
        shoppingList.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        shoppingList.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Word", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = shoppingList[indexPath.row].itemName
        cell.accessoryType = shoppingList[indexPath.row].checkmarkState ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            shoppingList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
            shoppingList[indexPath.row].checkmarkState = false
        } else {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
            shoppingList[indexPath.row].checkmarkState = true
        }
        
        save()
    }

    
    @objc func addTapped() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "New Shopping Item", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addTextField()
        
        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) {
            [weak self, weak ac] _ in
            guard let item = ac?.textFields?[0].text else { return }
            self?.addItem(item)
        }
        
        ac.addAction(addAction)
        
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func shareTapped() {

    }
    
    func addItem(_ item: String) {
        let itemCapitalised = item.capitalized
        shoppingList.insert(ShoppingList(itemName: itemCapitalised), at: 0)
        
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        save()
    }
    
    func showErrorMessage(errorTitle: String, errorMessage: String) {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: errorTitle, message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
    
    func save() {
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        
        if let savedData = try? jsonEncoder.encode(shoppingList) {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(savedData, forKey: "shoppingList")
        } else {
            print("Failed to save people.")
        }
    }
    
    func load() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        if let savedList = defaults.object(forKey: "shoppingList") as? Data {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                shoppingList = try jsonDecoder.decode([ShoppingList].self, from: savedList)
            } catch {
                print("Failed to load List")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Core data is probably a better data storage solution for a project such as this. You would then simply have a `checked` property on your to do entity.

Comment: you could save the index of the selected cell on your `UserDefault` however as @Paulw11 suggested CoreData is better for this use-case. Here it is a simple tutorial: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Comment: It depends on the dataset of table view guy.

Comment: I don't understand why core data is recommended.  If you have a few items, you need no search, no relationships between objects etc, then Core Data is too complex. It's not a problem to use User Defaults (you can store it as a JSON-encoded data) or even a simple file in app directory.

Comment: Create a struct that holds the shoping list string and the checkmark as a boolean and then use an array of this struct in your table view and persist it instead of the current array.

Comment: Just add `cell.accessoryType = shoppingList[indexPath.row].checkmarkState ? .checkmark : .none` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have stored `checkmarkState` in your model, simply add `cell.accessoryType = shoppingList[indexPath.row].checkmarkState ? .checkmark : .none` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` to render the checkmark state.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Word", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = shoppingList[indexPath.row].itemName
    cell.accessoryType = shoppingList[indexPath.row].checkmarkState ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

Also, there is a better way to write your `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`: Just invert the `checkmarkState`, then reload the row.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    shoppingList[indexPath.row].checkmarkState = !shoppingList[indexPath.row].checkmarkState
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    save()
}
```

Try to keep in mind the MVC philosophy. Never determine the state of your model by the UI view. Only determine the state of UI view by the model. When you receive user input, change the model directly, then re-render the view accordingly. Keep the model as single source of truth.

Comment: Thanks Ricky It Works, I have two more questions though 

1. how to check if an Item already exists in the data model? Before I used the following line inside the addItem function while using a normal array,

if shoppingList.contains(where: { $0.compare(item, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame })

2. Also in the shareTapped method I used 

let list = shoppingList.joined(separator: "\n")
for sharing the list, how do I achieve the same now

Comment: You can write `shoppingList.contains(where: { $0.itemName.compare(item.itemName, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame })` to compare and `let list = shoppingList.map{$0.itemName}.joined(separator: "\n")` to create the sharing string.

Comment: Thanks once again Ricky, Now my Project is complete and I learned a few things.